# Solving drilling positions using Solve or Trigonometry

Tags: equation-solving, fitting, geometry, trigonometry, engineering

I'm working on a profile where I need to position defined points: $ x1 $, $ x2 $, and $ x3 $

[image: imagem1]

With the code below I get these values using Approximate Functions `Fit`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

top = {103.4, 201, 295};
below = {161, 337.5, 507.3};
h = 525;

newBelow = below + 15;

data1 = {{newBelow[[1]], 0}, {top[[1]], h}};
eq1 = Fit[data1, {1, x1}, x1];
Solve[eq1 == (525 - 18), x1] /. Rule -> Set;

data2 = {{newBelow[[2]], 0}, {top[[2]], h}};
eq2 = Fit[data2, {1, x2}, x2];
Solve[eq2 == (525 - 18), x2] /. Rule -> Set;

data3 = {{newBelow[[3]], 0}, {top[[3]], h}};
eq3 = Fit[data3, {1, x3}, x3];
Solve[eq3 == (525 - 18), x3] /. Rule -> Set;

{x1, x2, x3} = Join[{x1}, Differences[{x1, x2, x3}]]
```

These are the values obtained:

> $x_1=105.889$, $x_2=100.305$ and $x_3=96.5989$

**I would like friends in the community to come up with different ideas that offer the same result.**

Comment: Are you looking for an equation of a line given two points? I.e. `y = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1) + y1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this way of solving it:

```
x1 = Rescale[18, {0, 525}, {103.4, 161 + 15}];
x2 = Rescale[18, {0, 525}, {201, 337.5 + 15}] - x1;
x3 = Rescale[18, {0, 525}, {295, 507.3 + 15}] - (x1 + x2);
{x1, x2, x3}
```

> ${105.889,100.305,96.5989}$

Or if you prefer a very concise version (that might not be as readable as the previous one):

```
Rescale[18, {0, 525}, {#1, #2 + 15}] & @@@ Transpose[{top, below}];
{x1, {x2, x3}} = {%[[1]], Differences[%]};
{x1, x2, x3}
```

> ${105.889,100.305,96.5989}$

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Interpolation` to find intermediate values, with the `InterpolationOrder` option set to 1 in order to ensure linear interpolation:

```
line1 = Interpolation[{{0, 103.4}, {525, 161 + 15}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
line2 = Interpolation[{{0, 201}, {525, 337.5 + 15}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
line3 = Interpolation[{{0, 295}, {525, 507.3 + 15}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

{line1[18], line2[18] - line1[18], line3[18] - line2[18]}
```

> {105.889, 100.305, 96.5989}